# How to sort on an weighted average field for term json faceting solr

Tags: solr, facet

I have a field reviewCount and totalCourseRating(sum of all the ratings) in each doc. I want to sort results based on the weighted average of these two fields. I want to do something like this:

```
json.facet={"categories" : {"type": "terms", "field": "instituteId", "limit": 40 ,sort:"aggregateReview desc", facet:{ "aggregateReview":"div(sum(totalCourseRating),sum(courseReviewCount))"}}}
```

but this gives error as div is not aggregation.